# Structure Constants for Matrix Coefficients

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

- **Background**:

If $U$ is a complex representation of a group $G$ with an inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ and $a,b\in U$ then $\langle a,\rho_U(g)b\rangle_U$ or $\langle a,gb\rangle$ for short is called a **matrix function** $G\to\mathbb{C}$. The coordinate version of Schur Orthogonality Relations says that if $U^{(1)},\cdots,U^{(k)}$ are the irreps of $G$ where $U^{(\ell)}$ has dimension $d_{\ell}$ and an orthonormal basis $u^{(\ell)}_1,\cdots,u_{d_{\large \ell}}^{(\ell)}$ with corresponding matrix coefficients $u_{ij}^{(\ell)}$ then $\{ \sqrt{d_{\ell}}u^{(\ell)}_{ij}\mid 1\le \ell\le k,1\le i,j\le d_{\ell}\}$ is an orthonormal basis for $C(G)$, the inner product space of complex-valued functions on $G$ with inner product $\langle f_1,f_2\rangle=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}\overline{f_1(g)}f_2(g)$. This follows from the formula

$$ \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G} \overline{\langle a,gb\rangle}\langle c,gd\rangle=\frac{\langle c,a\rangle\langle b,d\rangle}{\dim U} $$

where $U\ni a,b, V\ni c,d$ are irreps, assumed either equal or orthogonal so the RHS makes sense.

- **Question**:

Using matrix coefficients as a basis for the algebra $C(G)$, what are the structure coefficients? That is, if we multiply two matrix coefficients $\langle a,gb\rangle\langle c,gd\rangle$ we should be able to express it as a combination of matrix coefficients $\langle e,gf\rangle$. To extract out the components for such a function $\langle e,gf\rangle$ in the sum, we essentially need to be able to evaluate

$$ \sum_{g\in G}\langle a,gb\rangle \langle c,gd\rangle\overline{\langle e,gf\rangle} \tag{$\ast$}$$

for irreps $U\ni a,b,V\ni c,d, W\ni e,f$.

Can we express $(\ast)$ in terms of inner products of $a,b,c,d,e,f$; the Clebsch-Gordan coefficients of $U,V,W$ (and their duals if necessary) (i.e. the structure constants of the representation ring); and their dimensions? Or is this info insufficient?

- **Effort**:

If we proceed the same way we do for proving Schur Orthogonality for matrix coefficients, we may rewrite the summands of $(\ast)$ as $\langle a\otimes c,g(b\otimes d)\rangle \langle f,g^{-1}e\rangle$ (note the tensor product of inner product spaces is itself an inner product space) to get

$$ \left\langle a\otimes c,\sum_{g\in G}\langle f,g^{-1}e\rangle g(b\otimes d) \right\rangle $$

The sum after the comma, interpreted as a function $\Phi_{f,b,d}(e)$, is an intertwiner $W\to U\otimes V$. At this point we would have invoked Schur's lemma on $\Phi$ for proving Schur Orthogonality, but that doesn't apply here since $U\otimes V$ needn't be an irrep, and in general may have multiple $W$-type irreps contained in it.